# Who piloted the First Death Star?

Tags: star-wars, death-star

Who piloted the First Death Star? Was it a team of Imperial Navy marines or some other Imperial unit?

---

I'm fairly sure that its *not* Gary the Stormtrooper:

https://youtube.com/clip/UgkxLO-gY4RrnfgS_B38XmIbj7wwbFThIZr7

Comment: I would assume it would have a Bridge similar to those on the Star Destroyers. Also worthy of note is the "big screen room" where Krennic shows off the Death Star's weaponry.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot Krennic's room might only be for presentation purposes as we don't see it in ANH

Comment: Of course only commenting as a potential because I don't know for sure.

Comment: Frank Grimes, or Grimey, as he liked to be called.

Comment: @Skooba I've updated the video link, but it might not be showing the video frame

Answer (score 31, accepted):

## [Death Star Troopers](https://www.starwars.com/databank/death-star-troopers)

The Star Wars Databank has the following to say on them (emphasis mine).

> Death Star Troopers were the elite of the Imperial Navy who were stationed aboard the first and second Death Star. **They were responsible for piloting the super-structure to its destinations** and firing the superlaser on the orders of those in command of the station. They wore black uniforms and flared, reflective helmets

And if you don't want to click the link, the Death Star Troopers are these guys.

[image: Death Star Trooper]

Comment: Not to be confused with [Death Metal Troopers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=34XfTL2TL7U)

Comment: Is it said anywhere what the purpose of those huge helmets is? Why would they need a reflective helmet in such a position, anyway? It's hard to picture what that helmet could be protecting them from, given the relatively safe position that they're in.

Comment: @kat never looked into it, probably worthy of its own question if there isn’t one already.

Comment: The helmets are just part of the uniform, like pointy wizard hats.